# Batch iOS Push Notification

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

First of all thanks for your attention. The escenario here is that I need to send the same PUSH notification to thousands of devices. I've been reading the Apple documentation regarding to this topic and I found out that I have to batch multiple notifications.
The theory is clear, but I'm having doubts in the implementation.

For example, I normally use this PHP webservice to send one notification:

```php
$deviceToken = 'f9082e0e26fe72f4c9ef04bff33b8274186b51abeecb86e4a4e7ac773081****';
$passphrase = '********';
$message = "Hi, world";
$badge = 2;

$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

// Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
    $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

if (!$fp)
    exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

// Create the payload body
$body['aps'] = array('alert' => $message, 'sound' => 'default', 'badge'=>$badge);
$body['mis_parametros'] = array('hora' => date("F j, Y, g:i a"));

// Encode the payload as JSON
$payload = json_encode($body);

// Build the binary notification
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload))  .$payload;

// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

if (!$result)
echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
else
    echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL. ' to device token: '. $deviceToken;

// Close the connection to the server
fclose($fp);
```

I don't see how I am supposed to send them in batch. Should I call:

```php
// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));
```

then change the deviceToken and call again

```php
// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));
```

and finally, after all the notifications, close the connection to APNs calling ??

```php
// Close the connection to the server
fclose($fp);
```

I'll be waiting your answer, guys. I hope this code also helps people who are implementing the server side for sending normal PUSH notifications.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: did you able to solve your problem?

Comment: No, we are still not sure if we were doing it right. Anyway, we have decided to implement the server side in Java using Java-APNS (https://github.com/notnoop/java-apns) which handles multiple notifications services.

Comment: I see some implementation get an array of tokens, then loop through each token, calling the line that sends the push notification. So basically it's a single push notification logic, but with an array loop to push to each token in their database, before closing the stream to Apple's Push server.